Can 1x8 square-cut pine boards be used as wall sheathing for 2x4 16" o.c.?
Can 1x8 square cut pine boards be used as wall sheathing on a 2x4 wall 16" o.c.?  I have a bad shoulder and am working alone and therefore looking for something easier to manage than 4x8 panels. This would be for an 8x20 single-storey outbuilding.
P.S. This would be on the exterior but it isn't intended as the final  outside cladding, just the structural sheathing required to prevent racking and satisfy wind-shear requirements.  It would be MCA-treated for ground contact, most likely.
I've seen old garages that use this and are doing fine after 60 years, but I don't know if US code now requires single panels once the building exceeds a certain size. I'm in Pennsylvania.

Sure, they can be.  Are they the best option?   Maybe,  maybe not.
If this is just a shed for tool storage and you are talking about the inside, go for it.
If you are wishing to do the pine on the outside, It is a poor choice. pine does not stand up to weather well at all. Consider a cement based or vinyl siding.

This would be on the exterior but it isn't intended as the final  outside cladding, just the structural sheathing required to prevent racking and satisfy wind-shear requirements.  It would be MCA-treated for ground contact, most likely.
